# Middleware with generic communication media layer

Tags: c++, boost, communication, network-protocols

Greetings all,

I'm trying to implement middleware (driver) for an embedded device with generic communication media layer. Not sure what is the best way to do it so I'm seeking an advice from more experienced stackoverflow users:). Basically we've got devices around the country communicating with our servers (or a pda/laptop in used in field). Usual form of communication is over TCP/IP, but could be also using usb, RF dongle, IR, etc. The plan is to have object corresponding with each of these devices, handling the proprietary protocol on one side and requests/responses from other internal systems on the other.

The thing is how create something generic in between the media and the handling objects. I had a play around with the TCP dispatcher using boost.asio but trying to create something generic seems like a nightmare :). Anybody tried to do something like that? What is the best way how to do it?

Example: Device connects to our Linux server. New middleware instance is created (on the server) which announces itself to one of the running services (details are not important). The service is responsible for making sure that device's time is synchronized. So it asks the middleware what is the device's time, driver translates it to device language (protocol) and sends the message, device responses and driver again translates it for the service. This might seem as a bit overkill for such a simple request but imagine there are more complex requests which the driver must translate, also there are several versions of the device which use different protocol, etc. but would use the same time sync service. The goal is to abstract the devices through the middleware to be able to use the same service to communicate with them.

Another example: we find out that the remote communications with the device are down. So we send somebody out with PDA, he connects to the device using USB cable. Starts up the application which has the same functionality as the timesync service. Again middleware instance is created (on the PDA) to translate communication between application and the device this time only using USB/serial media not TCP/IP as in previous example.
I hope it makes more sense now :)

Cheers,
Tom

Comment: The title is confusing - device drivers are OS internal modules, but it looks like you are working in userland. Also, how does a USB or RF dongle communicate with the head office?

Comment: Hm, device driver is not OS internal module (even if it's usually the first thing which comes to mind). It's just a program which allows some higher level stuff to talk to the device. How else would you call it? 
Head office could be even one laptop, but will edit the post to make it clearer :)

Comment: Hmm, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver

Comment: Something like a block diagram to show what is talking to what would be great.  I tried drawing one myself, but couldn't get anywhere.  BTW, a program that passes data, unchanged, from one interface to another can be called a bridge or repeater.  The term "device driver" would work if your code were running on the embedded device and talked directly to the hardware (USB, Ethernet, whatever), but that doesn't sound like what you have.

Comment: "In computing, a device driver or software driver is a computer program allowing higher-level computer programs to interact with a hardware device." - I'm sorry, but isn't it what I just said? The only difference is that instead of typical bus our devices communicate over TCP/IP network, USB, etc. I agree that it might be confusing so I ask again how would you call it?

Comment: @Mike - it's not just passing data, it's "translating" them (as normally driver would do I imagine). I'll try to add example to the post. Again the only difference between normal driver and our driver I can see is the media over which the device and driver communicates (instead of computer bus it's network/usb cable/...)

Comment: Don't mean to be a pain, but OS and its device drivers are "computer programs" that interact with hardware :) Now the real questions - how does *your software* interact with the hardware? - what is "head office"? BTW, the name you are looking for is probably "plugin".

Comment: I think I described in the example, didn't I? Tell me what is the difference between OS asking harddisk to give it some data (meaning has to ask driver to translate it for the harddisk firmware) and my service asking the device to give it data (meaning has to ask the driver to translate it for the device firmware). How does OS interact with the harddisk? Btw. plugin is something else - it extends the capability of a program (see wiki). How does my "translator" (driver) extends capability of the service? It is only able to ask for the time regardless how many different drivers is out there.

Comment: "Middleware" may be a better term; it is code that lives between the system services layers (TCP, USB, whatever) and the application, making the various hardware architectures look more generic to the application.  Device drivers live in the OS and typically run as if they were part of the OS; your program looks like it lives in user space. Regarding your example: "New driver instance is created"... on the server? And one final question: Windows or Linux/Unix/Mac or something else?

Comment: Ok, let's call it middleware then :). For my question it doesn't really matter how we call it. I'll change the post. Yes, the middleware sits on the server (or laptop/pda). The main application (services) will run on Linux but the "proxies" (some of the services) can run on Win as well (one of the reason for middleware and boost)

Comment: OS interacts with hardware via I/O ports/memory, DMA, and interrupts. In userland you have device files and system calls.

Comment: If by OS you mean the driver (as part of OS) then I'm not really sure what was the point of the comment. For general definition of driver it doesn't matter HOW the driver does it, the important thing is that it provides the interface which allows the interaction between the device and program at higher level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing is how create something generic in between the media and the handling objects. I had a play around with the TCP dispatcher using boost.asio but trying to create something generic seems like a nightmare :). Anybody tried to do something like that? What is the best way how to do it?

I haven't used Boost, but the way I usually handled that kind of problem was to create a Device base class which the server interacts with, and then subclassed it for each device type, and made the subclasses deal with the device oddness.  That way, the Device class becomes a definition of your protocol.  Also, the Device class would need to be portable, but the subclasses would not.

If you had to get fancier than that, you could use the Factory pattern to create the actual subclassed objects.

As far as actually communicating, I'd see if I could just run one process per Device.  If you have to have more than one Device per process, on Linux I'd just use `select()` and its friends to manage I/O between the various Device instances.  I don't know how to do that on Windows; its `select` only works for sockets, not serial ports or other file-like things.

Other things that come to mind that might be useful include dbus and the MPI (Message Passing Interface) library, though they aren't complete solutions for your problem (dbus doesn't do inter-computer communications, IIRC).

Does this help at all?

EDIT: Needed a formatted response to Tom's reply...

> Does your device class contain the communication specific parts? Because that's the thing I wanted to avoid.

The *subclasses* contain the communication specific parts.  That's the whole point of using subclasses here; the generic stuff goes in the base class, and the specifics go in the subclass.

> I was thinking about something like this: Say there is a dispatcher specific for media used which creates Connection object for each connection (media specific), Device obj. would be created as well but just a generic one and the Connection would pass the incoming data to Device and the Device would pass the responses back to Connection.

I think that may be a bit complex, and you're expecting a generic Device to deal with a specific Connection, which can get hard to maintain fast.

What I'd recommend is a Device subclass specifically for handling that type of Connection which takes the Connection from the dispatcher and owns it until the connection closes.  Then your manager can talk to the generic Device and the Connection can mess with the specifics.

An example: Say you have a temperature sensor USB thingamajig.  You have some dispatcher that catches the "USB thing plugged in" signal.  When it sees the USB thing plugged in:

- Dispatcher creates a `USBTemperatureThingConnection`.
- Dispatcher creates a `USBTemperatureDevice`, which is a subclass of Device, giving the `USBTemperatureThingConnection` to the `USBTemperatureDevice` as a constructor parameter.
- `USBTemperatureDevice::USBTemperatureDevice(USBTemperatureThingConnection* conn)` goes and sets up whatever it needs locally to finish setting up the Connection, then sends a message to the Device Manager saying it has set itself up.

Some time later, the Device Manager wants to set the time on all devices.  So it iterates through its list of devices and calls the generic (maybe even abstract) `Device::SetTime(const struct timespec_t&)` method on each of them.

When it gets to your temperature device, it calls `USBTemperatureDevice::SetTime(const struct timespec_t&)`, since `USBTemperatureDevice` overrode the one in `Device` (which was either abstract, i.e. `virtual void SetTime(const struct timespec_t&) = 0;` or a no-op, i.e. `virtual void SetTime(const struct timespec_t&) {}`, so you don't have to override it for devices that can't set time).  `USBTemperatureDevice::SetTime(const struct timespec_t&)` does whatever USB Temperature sensor-specific things are needed, using the `USBTemperatureThingConnection`, to get the time set.

Some time later, the device might send back a "Time Set Result" message, saying if it worked or not.  That comes in on the `USBTemperatureThingConnection`, which wakes up your thread and you need to deal with it.  So your `USBTemperatureDevice::DealWithMessageFromSensor()` method (which only exists in `USBTemperatureDevice`) dives into the message contents and figures out if the time setting worked or not.  It then takes that result, turns it into a value defined in `enum Device::ResultCode` and calls `Device::TimeSetComplete(ResultCode result)`, which records the result, sets a flag (`bool Device::timeComplete`) saying the result is in, and then hits a `Semaphore` or `Condition` to wake up the Device Manager and get it to check all the `Device`'s, in case it was blocked waiting for all the devices to finish setting time before continuing.

I have no idea what that pattern is called.  If pressed, I'd say "subclassing", or "object-oriented design" if I felt grumpy.  The "middleware" is the `Device` class, the DeviceManager, and all their underlings.  The application then just talks to the Device Manager, or at most to the generic `Device` interface of a specific device.

> Btw. Factory pattern was planned, each object would run in separate thread :)

Good to hear.

Comment: Mike, does your device class contain the communication specific parts? Because that's the thing I wanted to avoid. I was thinking about something like this: Say there is a dispatcher specific for  media used which creates Connection object for each connection (media specific), Device obj. would be created as well but just a generic one and the Connection would pass the incoming data to Device and the Device would pass the responses back to Connection. Is there any pattern for this type of interaction between objects? Btw. Factory pattern was planned, each object would run in separate thread :)

Comment: Mike, sorry for late reply. I guess this something I had in mind :). Cheers. Thanks! :) Just note it's the same device with usb/eth/... ports - that was my reasoning behind the "generic device" for all the communications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by TCP/IP you mean remote nodes, and by USB, etc. the local devices connected to the same physical box. I think what I'm missing in your explanation is the part that announces the new local devices to the server process ( i.e. the analog of a listening socket) Again, assuming something along the lines of Linux `uevent`, I would start with the following structure:

- Controller: knows correct time, manages event sources, reacts to events
- Event source: produces "new/delete device" events, knows its device class

  - server socket
  - local device monitor
  - etc.
- Device class: encapsulates device-specific logic and manages/enumerates devices

  - remote device type (connected socket)
  - USB device type
  - USB device version X.Y.Z type
  - etc.

The high-level protocol is very simple - on receipt or "new device" event, *query* the "Device class" for time from given device, then *update* the time on the device. The "Device class" is the driver/translator/bridge that implements the conversion from query/update interface to device-specific commands (network exchange for remote nodes.) It also holds a list of its devices.

This should easily map to a class diagram. Was there something else that I missed?

Comment: I guess this is something I wanted to avoid - there is (should be) only one device class (ignoring the fact that there are different version of device), this middleware translates same messages no matter what media the came through (protocol/communication is the same regardless of the media used). Btw. the controller concept was used in the old implementation and caused us much headache - bear in mind that there are thousands of devices and there are many tasks controller has to do (updating time is one of the simpler).

Comment: @Tom: You have two levels here - a generic protocol between your app and a "virtual" device, and set of protocols for each particular device. Narrow down the functionality you want to expose from devices to the app, define a meaningful interface between the app and a device, implement protocol translation in the "class/driver/whatever" layer. Other then that, I don't see what you are looking for.

Comment: Hm, looks like I lack the skill to explain it to you. Thanks for the effort anyway :)